# Command "docker_installer" is not defined

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, docker

```
root@Client9:/var/azuracast# ./docker.sh install
Checking installation requirements for AzuraCast...
[PASS] Operating System: Linux
[PASS] Architecture: x86_64
[PASS] Command Present: curl
[PASS] Command Present: awk
[PASS] User Permissions
[PASS] Installation Directory
[PASS] All requirements met!
Docker is already installed! Continuing...
Docker Compose is already installed. Continuing...
Prefer stable release versions of AzuraCast? [y/N] y
Pulling installer ... done
Creating network "azuracast_installer_default" with the default driver
Creating azuracast_installer_installer_run ... done


  Command "docker_installer" is not defined.


ERROR: 1
Pulling mariadb  ... done
Pulling redis    ... done
Pulling stations ... done
Pulling web      ... done
Creating network "azuracast_backend" with driver "bridge"
Creating network "azuracast_frontend" with driver "bridge"
Creating volume "azuracast_db_data" with default driver
Creating volume "azuracast_letsencrypt" with default driver
Creating volume "azuracast_letsencrypt_acme" with default driver
Creating volume "azuracast_shoutcast2_install" with default driver
Creating volume "azuracast_geolite_install" with default driver
Creating volume "azuracast_sftpgo_data" with default driver
Creating volume "azuracast_station_data" with default driver
Creating volume "azuracast_www_vendor" with default driver
Creating volume "azuracast_www_uploads" with default driver
Creating volume "azuracast_tmp_data" with default driver
Creating volume "azuracast_redis_data" with default driver
Creating volume "azuracast_backups" with default driver
Creating azuracast_mariadb  ... done
Creating azuracast_stations ... done
Creating azuracast_redis    ... done
Creating azuracast_web_run  ... done
Starting up AzuraCast services...
️－－ Waiting...Services started up and ready!
This script must be run as the "azuracast" user. Rerunning...
AzuraCast Setup
(Environment: production)
```

I am trying to install AzuraCast using docker on Ubuntu 20.04 but constantly getting this error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You're not following the [installation instructions](https://docs.azuracast.com/en/getting-started/installation/docker).

Comment: @harrymc I have followed the installation instructions and I was able to install it, now I cannot access it on the server IP on the default 80 port, I tried changing the port to 7000 but that didnt work either